# Saving an image file from res/drawable to Gallery App in android

Tags: android, drawable, photo-gallery

I would like to know how to save an image from res/drawable folder into the device's gallery application, such that, image will be displayed in a customized (with a different name) location, e.g. pictures taken from other apps is displayed in a location in the gallery app as "Other". Thank you in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Store the image on sdcard and MediaScannerService will automatically recognize it.

Comment: Thank you. How about making a customized location for it?

Comment: Actually, MediaScannerService scans the internal storage (/) and sdcard. So the file should be present either internal storage or sdcard, under any path/directory.